# c++ stl string <bad ptr> but there is string value what does it mean?

Tags: c++, string

I have a C++ application that I'm setting a simple text string in `std::string` like this:

```
string foo = "my test string";
```

but when I see it in the debugger I'm getting this:

```
{_Buf=0x09d55c50 "my test string" _Ptr=0x74736e69 "‹MQhDqrtV‹ר‹VPכ‹URhDqrtP‹ר…uu‹Muƒֱ$טFo" }
```

or in a other string I'm getting this:

```
{_Buf=0x09d55c70 "some other string" _Ptr=0x7372614c <Bad Ptr> }
```

I'm hand typing it in to Visual Studio Express 2008, of course I found it after some other lib that was expecting this string kept getting exceptions.

When I changed it to `foo="";` everything worked fine.
The function of the lib api looks like this:

```
connect(const std::string& hostName, const std::string& userName, const std::string& password)
```

(MySQL C++ connector)

My question is what is this `_Ptr`, and more importantly why am I getting exceptions?

**UPDATE**
ok its really strange but the thing that cause me the exception is the length off the string 
only if i set 15 characters long string it go's ok but if i set longer string exception   is throwen . im using visual studio 2008 express 32 bit

Comment: Please, specify the question: whether it about the meaning of `_Ptr` member, or about exceptions you get with your library. In the latter case, you should create a separate question, actually.

Comment: When you say "must imported", do you mean "most important"?

Answer (score 8):

I think that what you're seeing is the "small string optimization" and `_Ptr` isn't valid (or it's being used for space) for your short strings.

EDIT: If you're passing `std::string` to another library as a `string` and not a `char*` then you need to make sure that your application is built with *exactly* the same compiler, version, options, optimization, debug settings, and standard library as the external library was. Otherwise the `string` ABI won't be guaranteed to be compatible and you'll get all sorts of unexplicable behavior.

Comment: so its better to pass it as char*?

Answer (score 1):

Are you building in debug mode?  The library is probably set up to accept release mode strings.  I suspect you'll find building for release will solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Those memory addresses appear to be in kernel space.  Check to see if your calling convention is wrong.  It would help if you could post a stack trace.

Comment: What kernel-space memory has to do with this?

Comment: Kernel-space has nothing to do with this.  I was thinking the structure was becoming corrupted, and I guessed it was because the calling convention was wrong.  I'm now thinking it's what Mark B said... a optimization

Answer (score 0):

IMO, `_Ptr` variable shouldn't be of concern - this is just of `_Elem` type, which is `char` for `basic_string`. It means `char*` - a basic memory location, not necessarily a valid C-string.